# Why is this php counter excecuting twice?

Tags: php

I made a counter when someone visits my website and it keeps executing twice when i get into it. you can also test it at www.krex.me

index.php

```
    <?php

include_once("counter.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>kreX.me</title>
<style>
a{
color:#333!important;
text-decoration:none !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;font-family:arial;">
    <h1 style="">Comming soon!</h1>
    <h2>Contact me!</h2>
    <h4><a href="https://web.facebook.com/leutrimo">Facebook - leutrimo</a></h4>
    <h4><a href="https://www.instagram.com/leutrimxosmani">Instagram - leutrimxosmani</a></h4>
    <h4><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/leutrim-osmani-b4056b74">
        Linked in - Leutrim Osmani
    </a></h4>
    <h4><a href="#">Email - trimi896@gmail.com</a></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

counter.php

```
    <?php

$datei = fopen("countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count++ ;
echo "$count" ;
echo " hits" ;
echo "\n" ;

$datei = fopen("countlog.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);

?>
```

it keeps excecuting twice and i dont know if its a problem in my code, a php bug or a problem in host. thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly makes you say that it is executing twice? What are you expecting the behavior to be? What is the _actual_ (unexpected) behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php#120520

Comment: Looking at your page it's not that it's excecuting twice. If that was the case there would be two outputs. What happens is that the count is +2. What happens if you use file_get_contents instead of fopen?

Comment: You have a strange host - even if I just open the countlog.txt file, it gets incremented every time! Not sure what you are running, but it isn't a "normal" setup.. Are there some .htaccess files?

Comment: the normal behavior would be that the increment would increase by 1 every time someone visits the site, but it keeps increment  by 2.
the host is in godaddy and .htaccess file has nothing in it

Comment: I also tried both, include and include_once. still the same result

Comment: Seems fine now, no?

Comment: Yeah, it was a hosting problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is misconfigured. The page loads twice every time. The `fav.ico` call executes it the second time.

You get the same behavior with `http://www.krex.me/not a real file`. Perhaps you have misconfigured a rewrite rule?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on fixing this issue?

Comment: I'd need to see the rewrites that are in place... Possibly just comment out the rewrites if you don't need them

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the host is configured to hold multiple domains. And while checking there was a .htaccess file inside one of the domain directories was reloading the request made from browser. I reset the file and now its working fine. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks.